# Where does Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition keep it's project files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration, windows-xp

Related to a previous question re. the debugger not working for me from VS Express:

[Visual Studio Express can't debug - "The debugger is not properly installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840542/visual-studio-express-cant-debug-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed/)

I established that the problem seemed to be with the particular project that VS had set up when I chose "Open Web Site > Filesystem". I would like to delete all references to this particular project and I'm wondering how to do this.

I can't find any options in VS and deleting the relevant folder from "C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects" (and "\Backup Files") didn't seem to reset whichever setting it is which causes my problem (indeed - the project still appears in the "recent projects" pane on the start page)

How can I remove all trace of my project so that I can re-create it without the broken debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio hasn't deleted it from the "recent projects" list because it doesn't realise you've deleted the website from the filesystem.

If you want the website to disappear from that list, click on it. Visual Studio will try and open it, realise it doesn't exist anymore and then remove it from the list.

Comment: I haven't deleted it from the filesystem though. I want the website to remain where it is but I want Visual Studio to loose all settings related to it (as for some reason debugging this instance of this website results in the problem I linked to above). Alternatively some kind of "clean project" option where VS forgot everything about the project would help...

Comment: I see. In that case, try temporarily renaming the file, opening it from the "Recent projects" list and then renaming it back. That should get it off of the list, but I'm not sure whether or not it will solve your debugging problem. Good luck!